# Dijkstra algorithm: should it work if there are 2 graphs that are not connected?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I have currently implemented Dijkstra's algorithm but the problem comes when I test my algorithm with a graph like this:
[image]

and try to go from C to B. And I know why it doesn't work. But I wonder if the normal implementation would work if there is a graph like this given?

```
  internal static Stack<string> Dijkstra(string sourcePoint, string targetPoint, Graph graph)
    {
        List<string> verticesStringList = graph.GetAllVertices();
        Dictionary<string, Vertex> verticesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Vertex>();
        InitializeVerticesDictionary(sourcePoint, verticesStringList, verticesDictionary);

        while (verticesDictionary.Values.ToList().Any(x => x.IsVisited == false))
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, Vertex> keyValuePair = verticesDictionary.Where(x => x.Value.IsVisited == false).ToList().Min();
            string vertexKey = keyValuePair.Key;
            Vertex currentVertex = keyValuePair.Value;
            List<string> neighbourVertices = graph.GetNeighbourVerticesSorted(keyValuePair.Key);
            foreach (string neighbourVertexString in neighbourVertices)
            {
                Vertex neighbourVertex = verticesDictionary[neighbourVertexString];
                int newDistanceFromStartVertex = currentVertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget + graph.GetEdgeWeight(keyValuePair.Key, neighbourVertexString);
                if (newDistanceFromStartVertex < neighbourVertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget)
                {
                    verticesDictionary[neighbourVertexString].ShortestDistanceFromTarget = newDistanceFromStartVertex;
                    verticesDictionary[neighbourVertexString].PreviousVertex = keyValuePair.Key;
                }
            }
            verticesDictionary[vertexKey].IsVisited = true;
        }

        return FormShortestPath(targetPoint, verticesDictionary);

    }

    private static Stack<string> FormShortestPath(string targetPoint, Dictionary<string, Vertex> verticesDictionary)
    {
        Stack<string> traverseStack = new Stack<string>();
        KeyValuePair<string, Vertex> vertex = verticesDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == targetPoint).FirstOrDefault();
        while (vertex.Value.PreviousVertex != null)
        {
            traverseStack.Push(vertex.Value.PreviousVertex + " Goes To " + vertex.Key); //the end edge
            vertex = verticesDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == vertex.Value.PreviousVertex).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return traverseStack;
    }



private static void InitializeVerticesDictionary(string sourcePoint, List<string> verticesStringList, Dictionary<string, Vertex> verticesDictionary)
    {
        foreach (string vertexString in verticesStringList)
        {
            Vertex vertex = new Vertex
            {
                ShortestDistanceFromTarget = int.MaxValue
            };

            if (vertexString == sourcePoint)
            {
                vertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget = 0;
            }

            verticesDictionary.Add(vertexString, vertex);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I changed my condition to `verticesDictionary.Values.ToList().Any(x => x.IsVisited == false && x.ShortestDistanceFromTarget != int.MaxValue)` and now I am not getting an overflow that I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work? if you are using while(true) and breaking when you process the destination node, thats the problem. Changing while true to while(there is something to process) would fix it

Comment: @juvian I am actually using the second approach you mentioned. The actual processing of the nodes isn't the problem. The problem comes when I backtrack my processed nodes

Comment: You should only backtrack when you actually reached that node, as ther is no path if you haven`t

Comment: @juvian at the moment my code in pseudocode is        while (collection contains an unvisited node){//logic currentNode.IsVisited=true}... after the loop finishesh I start making my path from the end to the start. So how should I know if there isn't a path to it?

Comment: check if destination node has IsVisited in true?

Comment: @juvian yes but I visit it since the while loop doesn't stop until I have visited all the nodes

Comment: From the vague description we can just conclude that there is something seriously wrong with your algorithm. Show it for getting better help.

Comment: @Henry ok but only the most significant part of the code, since I am using a lot of helpers

Comment: @Henry updated my question

Comment: You should not add all nodes to verticesDictionary, only source node

Comment: @juvian and add the neighbours in the loop right?

Comment: Your code does not follow what dijsktra should be doing, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode

Comment: @juvian maybe I should have showed my initialize method also

Comment: @juvian I don't get where I am mistaking... I followed the explanation of this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfj6mxhdMw and implemented it myself

Comment: In that case the distance between C and B should be  int.MaxValue

Comment: @juvian I realised that the integer overflows cuz of the condition verticesDictionary.Values.ToList().Any(x => x.IsVisited == false), thus at some moment a vertex with maxVal is reached and summed it overflows

Comment: @juvian Any ideas how to fix this bug, I think it has something to do with adding only the start node or something like that

Comment: don`t iterate neighbors when currentVertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget is int.maxVal

Comment: @juvian PS: the overflow happens in  currentVertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget + graph.GetEdgeWeight(keyValuePair.Key, neighbourVertexString); forgot to add :)

Comment: @juvian ok I fixed it.. If you could wrap all our chat in an answer so I can upvote and other people with the same problem can benefit from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsVisited` here is a bit misleading, as you can actually visit nodes that you can not reach from the source node. I would rename it to `isProcessed`. To check if you can reach from source node to another node you will need to check if its distance is `int.maxVal`.

To avoid overflow, do not iterate neighbors when currentVertex.ShortestDistanceFromTarget is `int.maxVal`, as it is already an unreachable node from source node.